# Extract a few character from a string

Tags: c#, string

I got the following problem:

I get Strings which contain somewhere a number, there is no pattern in the name.

For example:

```
string str1 = "new2string";

string str2 = "example1str";

string str3 = "str1example";
```

Now I need to extract a few character from each string before the number.
In every string is **always** a number. I need for example from string 1 "`new2`", from string 2 "`ple1`" and from string 3 "`str1`".

It shouldn't be that hard but I can't think of a small simple answer.

I would like to see some example from you guys!

Comment: Sounds like a regular expression of something like `[a-z]{3}\d` is your friend...

Comment: try this one    string word = "str1example";
            if (word.Length > 0)
            {
                int i = word.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
                string str = word.Substring(i-3,4);
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }

Comment: Is the number always preceded with 3 letters? Or can there be 1 or 2 only? What is a number: a digit, 1 or more digits? Floats? What is the expected result for `s1.23xxxxx`? Are the characters before the "number" alpha chars, or can be any non-whitespace/non-digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) is a powerfull tool to search for certain patterns in a `String`.

You can use the [`Regex.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) method to search for a pattern.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find a List of the possible pattern elements for C#.

As in your case Jon Skeet has already put a great solution in his comment.
As an alternative you also could use this pattern:

```
string searchPattern = @"\w{3}\d";
```

`\w{3}` means: exactly 3 occurrences of a word character followed by `\d` exactly 1 digit

You can use the pattern like this

```
string match = Regex.Match(str1, searchPattern).Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't used the Regex.Match method before. Now everything i wanted, works. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. You should read the documentation carefully. Consider the questions by @Wiktor Stribiżew. They point out very important points when you try to construct a search pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
var regex = new Regex(".{3}\\d");
var str1 = "example1str";
var res = regex.Match(str1).Value;
```

Comment: Hi Konstantin; your code-only answer would be better with some context. For example, if you explain how this solves the questioner's problem then it will be more useful to them, and also to other readers searching for answers to similar problems.